# Exception in observability stack after upgrading Spring Boot from 3.1.3 to 3.2.0 using opentelemetry-java

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry, micrometer-tracing, observability

**Problem:**

When upgrading the `observability` stack from Spring Boot version `3.1.3` to `3.2.0` using [OTel Java SDK](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java), the following exception is encountered:

```java
2023-11-26T16:00:43.087Z  WARN [order service,,] 1 --- [order service] [BatchSpanProcessor_WorkerThread-1] [] i.o.exporter.zipkin.ZipkinSpanExporter   : Failed to export spans

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "valid annotation timestamp required<EOL>"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:881)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:663)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.zipkin.ZipkinRestTemplateSender$RestTemplateHttpPostCall.doExecute(ZipkinRestTemplateSender.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.zipkin.ZipkinRestTemplateSender$RestTemplateHttpPostCall.doEnqueue(ZipkinRestTemplateSender.java:75)
    at zipkin2.Call$Base.enqueue(Call.java:406)
    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.zipkin.ZipkinSpanExporter.export(ZipkinSpanExporter.java:82)
    at io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.CompositeSpanExporter.lambda$export$3(CompositeSpanExporter.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.CompositeSpanExporter.export(CompositeSpanExporter.java:88)
    at io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.BatchSpanProcessor$Worker.exportCurrentBatch(BatchSpanProcessor.java:327)
    at io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.BatchSpanProcessor$Worker.run(BatchSpanProcessor.java:245)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**Configuration:**

Spring Boot Version: 3.2.0

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Tracing Dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Observations:**

Encountering a `HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest` exception when using the `observability` stack in Spring Boot version 3.2.0. The issue does not occur with version 3.1.3.

Any insights or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit-1:**

**Reproduction Steps**

- Clone the repository: [food-delivery-backend](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend)
- Checkout the branch/tag: `v3.2.0`
- Check [README.md](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/v3.2.0#readme) on how to run
- Now check the `order` API logs in [Grafana](http://localhost:3000)

**Additional Information**

- Working Sample (Spring Boot 3.2.0):
- [v3.2.0/restaurant](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/v3.2.0/restaurant) - No issues observed.
- Failing Sample (Spring Boot 3.2.0):
- [v3.2.0/order](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/v3.2.0/order) - Exception occurs.

**Edit-2:**

- The error is not present when using Spring Boot version `3.1.3` for both `brave` and `opentelemetry-java` dependencies - [Example](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/v3.1.3)
- The issue seems to be related to the interaction between Spring Boot 3.2.0 with `opentelemetry-java`

**Edit-3:**

**Spring Boot 3.2.0** uses following tracing versions

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
    <version>1.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Spring Boot 3.1.3** uses following tracing versions

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
    <version>1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I attempted different permutations of tracing versions with Spring Boot 3.2.0 to identify the specific dependency responsible for the exception. However, the issue persists with the following combinations:

1. **Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Micrometer Tracing 1.2.0 and OTel Exporter
   Zipkin 1.25.0**

Code: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/micrometer-tracing-1.2.0-opentelemetry-1.25.0)

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
  <version>1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. **Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Micrometer Tracing 1.1.4 and OTel Exporter Zipkin 1.31.0**

Code: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/micrometer-tracing-1.1.4-opentelemetry-1.31.0)

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
 <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
 <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
 <version>1.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In both cases, the exception persists. It remains unclear which specific combination of tracing versions with Spring Boot 3.2.0 triggers the issue.

**Edit-4:**

After implementing a minimal setup as suggested by @Jonatan Ivanov in the comments, I established two configurations—one utilizing an H2 database and the other incorporating the `datasource-micrometer-spring-boot` dependency for micrometer tracing on top of H2. Upon executing the application with the `datasource-micrometer-spring-boot` dependency, I encountered an error in the logs, indicating a potential issue with that specific dependency.

Below is the dependency configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.ttddyy.observation</groupId>
    <artifactId>datasource-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the corresponding GitHub links:

1. With only H2:
   [GitHub Repository - Only H2](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/observability/tree/sb_3_2_0_db)
2. With H2 and `datasource-micrometer-spring-boot`:
   [GitHub Repository - H2 and Micrometer Tracing](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/observability/tree/sb_3_2_0_db_and_datasource_micrometer_tracing)

I have also raised a GitHub issue within the project, which can be found at:
[GitHub Issue - datasource-micrometer](https://github.com/jdbc-observations/datasource-micrometer/issues/30)

Comment: Could you add also `RestClient ` that throw this exception ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa This exception is logged when the application is started, but not when we are calling the API. If you need more information, I can push these changes to GitHub

Comment: Do you have Zipkin running and did you configure the Zipkin connection in your properties file? Because it looks like the Zipkin exporter cannot export your traces.

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN Same configuration is working with `3.1.3` with `RestTemplate`. But, when I changed it to `3.2.0` and started using `RestClient`, observed mentioned exception

Comment: Could you please check what happens if you use Brave instead of OTel? `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` and `io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave`

Comment: @JonatanIvanov Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it looks good when using Brave dependencies. So, is it an issue with OTel dependencies? I have actually raised a GitHub issue in the Spring Boot repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38579

Comment: I saw your issue, I wanted to reply here to not duplicate things. You can stay on Brave, it should be transparent for you if the Zipkin format works. I think you can also move to the OTLP or Jaeger formats if you want. Could you please also open an issue for the OTel Java SDK? Please post the link here if you do so that we can follow.

Comment: Sure, @JonatanIvanov, I have updated the Stack Overflow question based on our findings and created a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/issues/6025.

Comment: One more thing you can help us to troubleshot this. Could you please check the OTel versions with Boot 3.1.3 and 3.2.0? Then could you please use Boot 3.2.0 (and Micrometer Tracing 1.2.0) but with the OTel versions that 3.1.3 uses. :)

Comment: @JonatanIvanov I attempted different permutations of tracing versions with Spring Boot `3.2.0`.

1. `Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Micrometer Tracing 1.2.0 and OTel Exporter Zipkin 1.25.0`, 

2. `Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Micrometer Tracing 1.1.4 and OTel Exporter Zipkin 1.31.0`. 

In both cases, the exception persists. It remains unclear which specific combination of tracing versions with Spring Boot `3.2.0` triggers the issue. Please check **Edit-3** for more information and sample code.

Comment: Did the Spring Boot 3.2, Micrometer Tracing 1.2 and Otel Exporter Zipkin 1.25.0 combo work?

Comment: @JonatanIvanov No, it's also throwing the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the collaboration on this, a bug was [identified](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/488) in Micrometer Tracing, [fixed](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/pull/487) then released ([1.2.1](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/releases/tag/v1.2.1)). Please upgrade your Micrometer Tracing version to use at least [1.2.1](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/releases/tag/v1.2.1) (you can also wait till the next Boot release (`3.2.1`) since it should pick up the fixed version).

Comment: I can still see the issue. Here you can see the code base which is upgraded to `1.2.1` - https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/food-delivery-backend/tree/v3.2.0

Comment: Can you make that reproducer minimal? I.e.: only one app if possible without the dependencies, e.g.: can you repro it without kafka just using an in-memory H2 DB?

Comment: It seems this is an issue with `net.ttddyy.observation:datasource-micrometer-spring-boot` dependency. I updated the question, please check **Edit-4**

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that upgrading `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel:1.2.1` would automatically bump up `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing` to the same version, but it didn't. After updating the Spring Boot version to `3.2.1`, both of these versions were upgraded to `1.2.1`, resolving the issue. My apologies for not thoroughly investigating this earlier.